# Getting data from one table using lists of other table php

Tags: php, pdo

I have following tables

myListTable

```
playerId listId type
 50       10     0
 51       10     0
```

players

```
id  x  xx etc
50  x  xx etc
51  x  xx etc
```

I want to run a query where i provide listId and type and it will get the lists of all players related to that listId and type

```
try {
    $conn = $this->GetDBConnection();
    $type = 0; // 0 REQUEST BY PLAYERS
    $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT p.* FROM myListTable c, players p WHERE (c.listId = :listId ) AND (c.type = :type) AND ( p.id = c.playerId) ');
    $statement->bindParam(':listId', $listId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->bindParam(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();
    if(!($row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) {
        return false;
    }
    $conn = null;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    throw $e;
}
```

This is just returning me false. What do i have to do to fix this query?

Comment: `:c.listId` should instead be `:listId`.

Comment: it is, type mistake in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the mistake is a typo in your prepare query:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT p.* 
    FROM myListTable c, players p 
    WHERE (c.listId = :c.listId ) 
        AND (c.type = :type) 
        AND ( p.id = c.playerId) ');
```

The `:c.listId` should just be `:listId`.

The second one is, `type` is a reserved word in MySQL. You need backticks to escape it inside your query.

Another is, since you're only selecting values from the `players` table; a `JOIN` is preferred.

The query should be:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM players p
JOIN myListTable c
    ON (p.id = c.playerId)
WHERE (c.listId = :c.listId)
    AND (c.`type` = :type)
```

Comment: all these changes and the result is still false :(

Comment: Even after using backticks for `type`?

Comment: right it worked. cool i changed the table name type to cType. Perfect and thanks.